# Block users not to access teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

Currently, in our tenant, users are accessing Microsoft Teams and getting licenses, so we have removed their licenses from the Azure portal, but they can log in to Teams and get the direct licenses.

We are looking for an approach to block Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure AD) users not to accessing Teams Explorer so that users won't get direct Teams exploratory licenses.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent users running the getting the direct license, you need to turn off the capability of running the Teams Exploratory experience.

There are [three options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-exploratory#prevent-users-from-installing-trial-apps-and-services) to achieve this:

1. You can turn off a user's ability to install trial apps and services, which would prevent the user from running the Teams Exploratory experience.
2. If your tenant has users with the self-service Teams Exploratory trial, you need to [use PowerShell to turn off a user's ability to install trial apps and services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/subscriptions/allowselfservicepurchase-powershell?view=o365-worldwide#example-script-to-disable-allowselfservicepurchase) by setting AllowSelfServicePurchase to "Disabled" for that product.
3. If your users have the tenant-based organizational Teams Exploratory trial, you need to sign into the **Microsoft 365 admin center** > go to **Settings** > **Org settings** > On the **Services** tab, scroll and then select User owned apps and services > on the pane, clear the check mark from **Let users install trial apps and services**.